# Inserting Multiple Rows Simultaneously with Rails3

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datamapper

We have an existing mysql database and a php front end which we're currently porting to a RoR3 application using Datamapper.

We need to insert multiple rows with a single commit, each using the same name. For example, if I look at the groups table, we have this structure:

```
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| groupname | varchar(64)      | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| attribute | varchar(64)      | NO   |     |         |                |
| op        | char(2)          | NO   |     | ==      |                |
| value     | varchar(253)     | NO   |     |         |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And the content looks like this:

```
+----+---------------------------+-------------------+----+------------+
| id | groupname                 | attribute         | op | value      |
+----+---------------------------+-------------------+----+------------+
|  1 | RADIUS-Disabled-Users     | Auth-Type         | := | Reject     |
|  2 | 30-minutes                | Huntgroup-Name    | == | xxx        |
|  3 | 30-minutes                | Simultaneous-Use  | := | 1          |
|  4 | 30-minutes                | Max-Daily-Session | := | 1800       |
|  7 | silver                    | Simultaneous-Use  | := | 25         |
+----+---------------------------+-------------------+----+------------+
```

As you can see, we have multiple rows with the same name, each with a different attribute and value.

In our view, I need a name field followed by a drop down menu for the attribute and a field for the value. Most importantly we need to be able to insert multiple rows in one move.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

No Problem,... Would be much code to explain but thanks god theres a raislcast series about this...

http://railscasts.com/episodes/73-complex-forms-part-1
http://railscasts.com/episodes/74-complex-forms-part-2
http://railscasts.com/episodes/75-complex-forms-part-3

hf,...

Comment: Cool, was kind of hoping there'd be a tutorial about it but hadn't thought to check railscasts yet. Will check them out...

Comment: I've worked my way through the railcasts but they don't quite answer my problem. One of my models doesn't have any nested attributes or children but it does take multiple attributes. That's why I'm using datamapper as I couldn't get active record to work with my column attrbiute. How can I add multiple attributes in my view?